# Autologin VBScript not working for PeopleSoft

Tags: vbscript, peoplesoft

In Peoplesoft ERP, there are many Processes which need to be run manually, once you login into PeopleSoft. We intend to automate this process, using VBS, since it justs involves a few clicks.  However, we stuck at the very first step, Login into the Peoplesoft. Below is the code as of now which we have tried. This opens the login page, but nothing further happens. Can someone help to log us in?

EDIT : We are in IE11

```vb
WScript.Quit Main

Function Main
    Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "our URl"
    Wait IE

    Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("userid")
    Helem.Value = "username"  
    Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("pwd")
    Helem.Value = "password" 
    Set Helem = IE.document.Forms(0)
    Helem.Submit
End Function

Sub Wait(IE)
    Do
        WScript.Sleep 500
    Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy 
    Do
        WScript.Sleep 500
    Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy 
End Sub

Sub IE_OnQuit
    On Error Resume Next
    WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "IE closed before script finished."
    WScript.Quit
End Sub
```

Please find below the HTML code:

```html
<html dir=ltr lang=en>
<head>
<title>Oracle PeopleSoft Sign-in</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=yes">  
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<script language="JavaScript">
var sDomain =  ";
try {
    document.domain =  ";
}
catch (err) {; }
</script>
<style id="ptfb" type="text/css">body{display:none;}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (self === top) {
    var fb = document.getElementById("ptfb");
    fb.parentNode.removeChild(fb);
} else {
    try { 
        top.location = self.location;
    } catch(ex) {}
}
</script>
<link  type="text/css" href="/PMXFGL01/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/PMXFGL01/signin.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="ptSignon().login();">
<div id="pswrapper">
  <form id="login" name="login" method="post" action="?&cmd=login&languageCd=ENG" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" id="timezoneOffset" name="timezoneOffset" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" id="ptmode" name="ptmode" value="f">
    <input type="hidden" id="ptlangcd" name="ptlangcd" value="ENG">
    <input type="hidden" id="ptinstalledlang" name="ptinstalledlang" value="GER,UKE,DAN,HUN,CFR,SLK,ENG,CZE,FRA,NOR,CRO,POR,ARA,ZHT,JPN,ZHS,RUS,POL,T    HA,ITA,GRK,ROM,KOR,TUR,SER,SVE,ESP,DUT,MAY,BUL,HEB,FIN,VIE,SLV">
    <div class="signonMain">
      <img src="/PMXFGL01/images/Header.png" class="ps-staticimg"     alt="Oracle PeopleSoft Sign-in" title="Oracle PeopleSoft Sign-in" >
      <div class="ps_signinentry" >
        <div id="ptloginerrorcont" class="ps_login_error" >
          <div class="ps_login_error_inner" role="heading" aria-level="2">
            <a id="error_link" name="error_link" tabindex="1"><img     src="/PMXFGL01/images/PT_LOGIN_ERROR.gif" alt="Error"></a>
            <div class="psloginerror" id="discovery_error"     name="discovery_error" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" ></div>
              <span class="psloginerror" id="login_error" name="login_error"     role="alert" aria-live="assertive">User ID and Password     are required.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="ps_box-control psloginerror"     id="browsercheck_error" name="browsercheck_error" aria-live="assertive"     role="alert"></div>
          </div>
          <div> 
            <span class="ps_label-show" id="ptLabelUserid"><label     for="userid">User ID</label></span>
          </div>
          <div class="ps_box-control">
            <input type="text" id="userid" name="userid" value="xxx"     title="User ID">
          </div>
          <div>
            <span class="ps_label-show" id="ptLabelPassword"><label for="pwd">Password</label></span>
          </div>
          <div class="ps_box-control">
            <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" title="Password" >
          </div>
          <div>
            <span class="ps_label-show" id="ptLabelSelect"><label for="ps_select_box">Select a Language</label></span>
          </div>
          <div id="ps_select_parent" >
            <div id= "ps_select_box" class="ps_box-control">            
              <select id="ptlangsel" name="ptlangsel"  title="Select a Language" class="ps_select" onChange="ptSignon().changeLangFunc(this, event)">
                <option value="ENG" title="English">English</option>
                <option value="UKE" title="UK English">UK English</option>
                <option value="ESP" title="Spanish">Espa&ntilde;ol</option>
                <option value="DAN" title="Danish">Dansk</option>
                <option value="GER" title="German">Deutsch</option>
                <option value="FRA" title="French">Fran&ccedil;ais</option>
                <option value="CFR" title="Canadian French">Fran&ccedil;ais&nbsp;du&nbsp;Canada</option>
                <option value="ITA" title="Italian">Italiano</option>
                <option value="HUN" title="Hungarian">Magyar</option>
                <option value="DUT" title="Dutch">Nederlands</option>
                <option value="NOR" title="Norwegian">Norsk</option>
                <option value="POL" title="Polish">Polski</option>
                <option value="POR" title="Portuguese">Portugu&ecirc;s</option>
                <option value="ROM" title="Romanian">Rom&#x00E2;n&#x0103;</option>
                <option value="FIN" title="Finnish">Suomi</option>
                <option value="SVE" title="Swedish">Svenska</option>
                <option value="TUR" title="Turkish">T&#x00FC;rk&#x00E7;e</option>
                <option value="CZE" title="Czech">&#x010C;e&#x0161;tina</option>
                <option value="JPN" title="Japanese">&#x65E5;&#x672C;&#x8A9E;</option>
                <option value="KOR" title="Korean">&#xD55C;&#xAD6D;&#xC5B4;</option>
                <option value="RUS" title="Russian">&#x0420;&#x0443;&#x0441;&#x0441;&#x043A;&#x0438;&#x0439;</option    >
                <option value="THA" title="Thai">&#x0E20;&#x0E32;&#x0E29;&#x0E32;&#x0E44;&#x0E17;&#x0E22;</option>
                <option value="ZHS" title="Simplified Chinese">&#x7B80;&#x4F53;&#x4E2D;&#x6587;</option>
                <option value="ZHT" title="Traditional Chinese">&#x7E41;&#x9AD4;&#x4E2D;&#x6587;</option>
                <option value="ARA" title="Arabic">&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0639;&#x0631;&#x0628;&#x064A;&#x0629;</option>
                <option value="VIE" title="Vietnamese">Ti&#7869;ng Vi&#7879;t</option>
                <option value="BUL" title="Bulgarian">&#x0431;&#x044a;&#x043b;&#x0433;&#x0430;&#x0440;&#x0441;&#x043a;&#x0438;</option>
                <option value="CRO" title="Croatian">hrvatski</option>
                <option value="GRK" title="Greek">&#x0395;&#x03bb;&#x03bb;&#x03b7;&#x03bd;&#x03b9;&#x03ba;&#x03ac;</option>
                <option value="HEB" title="Hebrew">&#x05e2;&#x05d1;&#x05e8;&#x05d9;&#x05ea;</option>
                <option value="MAY" title="Bahasa Malay">Bahasa     Melayu</option>
                <option value="SER" title="Serbian">&#x0441;&#x0440;&#x043f;&#x0441;&#x043a;&#x0438;</option>
                <option value="SLK" title="Slovak">sloven&#x010d;ina</option>
                <option value="SLV" title="Slovenian">sloven&#x0161;&#x010d;ina</option>
              </select>
            </div>     
          </div>
          <div class="ps_box-button">
            <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="ps-button" value="Sign In" aria-label='To enable Accessibility mode, please check the checkbox "Enable Accessibility Mode" before you sign in. Sign In'>
          </div>
          <div class="ps_box-button">
            <input type="checkbox" name="accessible" id="accessible">
            <label for="accessible">Enable Accessibility Mode</label>
          </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="ps_box-link">
          <span class="ps-link"></span>
        </div>
        <img src="/PMXFGL01/images/Footer.png" width="100%" alt="">
        <footer id="ptfooter" class="ps_footer_text ">Copyright &copy; 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved. </footer>
    </div>  
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the following is working for me on IE11:

```
Function Main
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://mysite/psp/myenvironment/?cmd=login"
Wait IE

With IE.Document
     .getElementByID("userid").value = "myUsername"
     .getElementByID("pwd").value ="myPassword"
     .getElementsByName("Submit")(0).click
End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Robin for the Answer. However, the script just stops after opening the login page. The text boxes are still not populated. Could it be Some issue with my IE security setting ?

Comment: does the script give you an error message? That it is not able to get the textboxes? Or is it just doing nothing? In case of the latter, it could be security settings.

Comment: It does nothing, just open the URlL, thats it. The text boxes are not  being populated. :-) Can you suggest any other way instead of using VBs ?

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct url? you need to enter the final location. not the default signon.html page.

Comment: Yes, the URL is :
http://****.**.***:9000/psp/domainname/?cmd=login&languageCd=ENG&"